# Python 3.x PIL image saving and rotating

Tags: python-3.x, rotation, save, python-imaging-library, exif

My code is:

```
from PIL.ExifTags import *
from PIL import Image
import sys
import os
import glob
import time

image_fileList = []
mainFolder = 'C:' + chr(92) + 'Users' + chr(92) + 'aa\Desktop\ToDigitalFrame\To select from'
folderList = [x[0] for x in os.walk(mainFolder)]
print(folderList)

def saveImage(imgName):
    imgName.save('rotated.jpg')

for folder in folderList:
    print(folder)
    for image_file in glob.glob(folder + '/*.jpg'):
        print(image_file)
        if not os.path.isfile(image_file):
            sys.exit("%s is not a valid image file!")

        img = Image.open(image_file)
        info = img._getexif()
        exif_data = {}
        if info:
            for (tag, value) in info.items():
                decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
                if type(value) is bytes:
                    try:
                        exif_data[decoded] = value.decode("utf-8")
                    except:
                        pass
                else:
                    exif_data[decoded] = value
        else:
            sys.exit("No EXIF data found!")

        print(exif_data)

        if exif_data['Orientation'] == 6:
            im = Image.open(image_file)
            im.rotate(280, expand=True).show()
            # saveImage(im)
            im.save('rotated.jpg')
        elif exif_data['Orientation'] == 3:
            im = Image.open(image_file)
            im.rotate(180, expand=True).show()
            saveImage(im)
        elif exif_data['Orientation'] == 8:
            im = Image.open(image_file)
            im.rotate(90, expand=True).show()
            saveImage(im)
        elif exif_data['Orientation'] == 4:
            im = Image.open(image_file)
            im.rotate(270, expand=True).show()
            saveImage(im)
```

In my pictures, the Orientation is mostly 6 (6 = Rotate 90 CW)I want to rotate them with 270 degrees.
So, my preview is:[image: preview]
And my saved output file is equal with the default file:[image: savedFile]

So, it doesn't really save the rotated picture, this code just saves the original picture one more time. 
I want to save the rotated picture! I know I'm rotating the picture with 280 degrees instead of 270 degrees but, just to show it doesn't save it.

Comment: Just a note here that using `im = ImageOps.exif_transpose(im)` (with import `from PIL import Image, ImageOps`) is much easier than all your if/else logic and will read the orientation from exif and rotate for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the Image.rotate() returns a rotated copy of this image.

so how about try:

```
  im = Image.open(image_file)
  im=im.rotate(270, expand=True)
  im.show()
  im.save('rotated.jpg')
```

see the docs:https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.rotate

Comment: This is a 404 error page. The link you have followed or the URL that you entered does not exist. It might be that the documentation has been updated, or this page has been removed.

Comment: @LifeafterGuest Thanks for your reminder! I have updated the new URL from stable document website.